# Vue 3 Composition API accordion component API calls

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5

I made a custom accordion component based on Bootstrap. I also made a custom tabs component based on Bootstrap, both for my Vue 3 Composition API app.

My Tab component receives:

- label
- Icon
- Component that it should render

My accordion component is the same.

Now, each component that I send to the Tabs component has different API calls, think getSettings, getLogo etc. The API calls only fire when I click the tab. So if I click the "Settings" tab, it just fires "getSettings" (backend call).

This works perfectly.

I want the same done with my Accordion component, but when I use it on a view, it just fires all the api calls in the components immediatly. I just want to fire the API calls in the component in the current accordion panel.

I thought this is maybe not possible for an accordion, because then it doesn't know the height of the panel needed, so this component works differently than the tabs component. But I don't want to just assume that and give up.

So my question is, is this possible? Is it possible to just fire the API calls of the current openend accordion item?

So, for example if I click on the Logo accordion item, it should only fire "getLogo" (backend call). Or is this impossible?

Here is my Tabs component:

```
<template>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-icons" :id="id" role="tablist" :class="{ 'nav-fill': isFullWidth }">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
        :key="index"
        :class="{ active: currentTab === index }"
        @click="currentTab = index">
      <button class="nav-link justify-content-center" :class="[{ active: currentTab === index }]" :id="index" data-bs-toggle="tab" :data-bs-target="tab.key + '-tab-pane'" type="button" role="tab" :aria-controls="tab.key + '-tab-pane'" aria-selected="true">
        <BootstrapIcon :icon="tab.icon" :variant="tab.iconVariant" />
        <span>{{ $t(tab.translation) }}</span>
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content my-4">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0">
      <component :is="tabs[currentTab].component"></component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue"
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n"

const { t } = useI18n()

const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tabs: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  isFullWidth: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
});

const currentTab = ref(0)


</script>
```

And here is my Accordion component:

```
<template>
  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" :id="id">
    <div class="accordion-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" :id="'heading-' + item.id">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" :data-bs-target="'#collapse' + item.id" :aria-expanded="currentItem === item.id ? 'true' : 'false'" :aria-controls="'collapse' + item.id" @click="currentItem = item.id">
          <BootstrapIcon :icon="item.icon"></BootstrapIcon>
          <span class="ms-3 font-weight-bold">{{ $t(item.translation) }}</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div :id="'collapse' + item.id" class="accordion-collapse collapse" :class="{ 'show': currentItem === item.id }" :aria-labelledby="'heading' + item.id" :data-bs-parent="'#' + id">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <component :is="item.component"></component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
})

const currentItem = ref(null)
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't how accordions usually work. You'd need to change v-if condition on click. That you use raw Bootstrap and not vue wrapper makes it less straightforward because you'll have to interact with BS scripts. Check bootstrap-vue-next, you can borrow and extend the implementation if you don't want to use it exclusively

Comment: Bootstrap-Vue package wasnt compatible last year when I started this app, hence the custom implementation.. I will look more into it...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer:

```
    <template>
  <div class="accordion accordion-flush" :id="id">
    <div class="accordion-item" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="'accordion-item-' + id + '-' + index">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" :id="'according-heading-' + item.id">
        <button
          class="accordion-button collapsed"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          :data-bs-target="'#collapse' + item.id"
          :aria-expanded="currentItem === item.id ? 'true' : 'false'"
          :aria-controls="'collapse' + item.id"
          @click="currentItem = item.id"
        >
          <BootstrapIcon :icon="item.icon"></BootstrapIcon>
          <span class="ms-3 font-weight-bold">{{ $t(item.translation) }}</span>
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div :id="'collapse' + item.id" class="accordion-collapse collapse" :class="{ 'show': currentItem === item.id }" :aria-labelledby="'heading' + item.id" :data-bs-parent="'#' + id">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <component v-if="currentItem == item.id" :is="item.component"></component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  items: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
})

const currentItem = ref(null)
</script>
```